# "HIBERNATE_SEQUENCE" not found

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, openjpa, jpa-2.1

I have two tables EmployeeGroup table and EmpplyeeDetails Table. EmployeeGroupTable has primary key groupid which should be generated from databse sequence GroupIdGenerator.
EmployeeDetails have two primary keys as groupid and employeeid. Groupid   should be same as of the previous table and employeeid should also have incremented value like 1,2,3.
These values in both table should insert in one transaction.
Can you help me with correct mapping?

I already tried with different combination of Generated value and Sequence generator but not able to save the data into table.

```
@Entity
   @Table(name="EMPLOYEE_GROUP")
   public class EmployeeGroup {

   @Column(name = "GROUP_ID")
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = 
      "groupid-gen")
   @Id
   @NotNull
   @SequenceGenerator(name = "groupid-gen", sequenceName = 
     "GROUIP_ID_GENERATOR" )
   private  long groupId;

   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "employeeDetail")
      private List<EmployeeDetail> employeeDetails;
      }



@Entity
   @Table(name = "EMPLOYEE_DETAIL")
   @IdClass(EmployeeID.class)
   public class EmployeeDetail {

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "GROUP_ID", insertable=false , updatable=false)
  private EmployeeGroup employeeGroup;

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = 
     "groupid-gen")
  @SequenceGenerator(name = "groupid-gen", sequenceName = 
    "GROUIP_ID_GENERATOR" )
  @Column(name = "GROUP_ID")
  @Nonnull
     private Long groupId;

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  @Nonnull
  @Column(name = "EMPLOYEE_ID")
    private Long employeeId;
```

}

```
public class EmployeeId{

private Long groupId;

private Long employeeId;

public EmployeeId(final Long groupId, final Long employeeId) {
    this.groupId = groupId;
    this.employeeId = employeeId;
}

public EmployeeId() {
}
```

}

Expected result is both table should have proper values like.

Table EmployeeGroup

```
 GroupID
   1
   2
```

Table EmployeeDetail

```
GroupId       EmployeeId
  1            1
  1            2
  1            3
  2            1
  2            2
```

I am getting error as 
   ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Sequence "HIBERNATE_SEQUENCE" 
   not found; SQL statement:
   call next value for hibernate_sequence [90036-197]
   org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not prepare 
   statement; nested exception is 
   org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not prepare statement

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Hi @SimonMartinelli I am using Oracle databse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing Id generator strategies:

In the class `EmployeeDetail` you have an Oracle Sequence for the `groupId` but `GenerationType.AUTO` for `employeeId`

This `GenerationType.AUTO` causes the problem.

Either you have to use a Oracle Sequence there as well or you must remove `@GeneratedValue` if this id comes from anywhere else.

Comment: I want employeeId to be an auto incremented value like 1,2,3 and do not want to use Oracle sequence for it. What would you suggest to achieve this?

Comment: Use a Oracle Sequence as well

Comment: Well this does remove the error however I did not achieve the end results so may be raising a different question for better understanding and will add link.

Comment: The other idea could be to create the hibernate_sequence table but this will give you the same result as with the Oracle sequence.

Comment: And please as my answer solved your initial problem I would appreciate it if you accept it as the correct answer. Thank you

Comment: Thanks Simon, yes it solved the initial problem :) Can you please give your suggestion on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56580313/jpa-entity-mapping-for-join-columns