# JPA Entity mapping for join columns

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.0, openjpa

I have three tables EmployeeDepartment, EmployeeGroup and EmpplyeeDetails Table. EmployeeDepartment table has primary key departmentId and a column groupId, EmployeeGroupTable has primary key groupid which should be generated from databse sequence GroupIdGenerator.
EmployeeDetails have two primary keys as groupid and employeeid. Groupid   should be same as of the previous table
These values in all table should insert in one transaction.
Can you help me with correct JAP Entity mapping?

I already tried with different combination of Generated value and Sequence generator but not able to save the data into table.

```
  @Entity
   @Table(name="EMPLOYEE_DEPARTMENT")
   public class EmployeeDepartment {

   @Column(name = "DEPARTMENT_ID")
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = 
      "departmentid-gen")
   @Id
   @NotNull
   @SequenceGenerator(name = "departmentid-gen", sequenceName = 
     "DEAPARTMENT_ID_GENERATOR" )
   private  long departmentId;

   @OneToOne(mappedBy = "employeeGroup")
      private EmployeeGroup employeeGroup;
      }
  @Coulmn(name="GROUP_ID") 
  private long groupId;




   @Entity
   @Table(name="EMPLOYEE_GROUP")
   public class EmployeeGroup {

   @Column(name = "GROUP_ID")
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = 
      "groupid-gen")
   @Id
   @NotNull
   @SequenceGenerator(name = "groupid-gen", sequenceName = 
     "GROUIP_ID_GENERATOR" )
   private  long groupId;

   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "employeeDetail")
      private List<EmployeeDetail> employeeDetails;

  @OneToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "DEPARTMENT_ID", insertable=false , 
        updatable=false)
      private EmployeeDepartment employeeDepatment;
      }



@Entity
   @Table(name = "EMPLOYEE_DETAIL")
   @IdClass(EmployeeID.class)
   public class EmployeeDetail {

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "GROUP_ID", insertable=false , updatable=false)
  private EmployeeGroup employeeGroup;

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = 
     "groupid-gen")
  @SequenceGenerator(name = "groupid-gen", sequenceName = 
    "GROUIP_ID_GENERATOR" )
  @Column(name = "GROUP_ID")
  @Nonnull
     private Long groupId;

  @Id
  @Nonnull
  @Column(name = "EMPLOYEE_ID")
    private Long employeeId;
```

}

```
public class EmployeeId{

private Long groupId;

private Long employeeId;

public EmployeeId(final Long groupId, final Long employeeId) {
    this.groupId = groupId;
    this.employeeId = employeeId;
}

public EmployeeId() {
}
```

}

Expected result in these 3 tables should have proper values like.

Table EmployeeDepartment

```
DepartmentID   GroupId
   1               1
```

Table EmployeeGroup

```
 GroupID  
   1
```

Table EmployeeDetail

```
GroupId       EmployeeId
  1            1
  1            2
  1            3
```

Actual results are below

Table EmployeeDepartment

```
DepartmentID   GroupId
   1               0
```

Table EmployeeGroup

```
 GroupID  
   1
```

Table EmployeeDetail

```
GroupId       EmployeeId
  2            1
  3            2
  4            3
```

Comment: Why does the employee have a composite primary key and not a sequence an then a foreign key to group?

Comment: Actually its a legacy domain model and for some reason we cannot change it. That leads to update my problem statement. So just consider these as composite keys not a foreign key.

Comment: But groupId is a foreign key and you have a sequence generator configured. How's that?

Comment: you mean to say in EmployeeDetail right? If I dont use it I get an exception like value cannot ne null for groupId while saving into EmployeeDetail.

Comment: Yes because if you want to add an employee you have to assign a group

Comment: thats correct but I dont know what mapping I should use if I dont use sequence generator in EmployeeDetail for column groupId

Answer (score 0):

The important annotation is `@MapsId("groupId")`

Your mapping should be something like this:

```
   @Entity
   @Table(name="EMPLOYEE_DEPARTMENT")
   public class EmployeeDepartment {

   @Column(name = "DEPARTMENT_ID")
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = 
      "departmentid-gen")
   @Id
   @NotNull
   @SequenceGenerator(name = "departmentid-gen", sequenceName = 
     "DEAPARTMENT_ID_GENERATOR" )
   private  long departmentId;

   @OneToOne(mappedBy = "employeeGroup")
   private EmployeeGroup employeeGroup;

   @Column(name="GROUP_ID") 
   private long groupId;


   @Entity
   @Table(name="EMPLOYEE_GROUP")
   public class EmployeeGroup {

   @Column(name = "GROUP_ID")
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = 
      "groupid-gen")
   @Id
   @NotNull
   @SequenceGenerator(name = "groupid-gen", sequenceName = 
     "GROUIP_ID_GENERATOR" )
   private  long groupId;

   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "employeeDetail")
   private List<EmployeeDetail> employeeDetails;

   @OneToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "DEPARTMENT_ID", insertable=false, updatable=false)
   private EmployeeDepartment employeeDepatment;


   @Entity
   @Table(name = "EMPLOYEE_DETAIL")
   @IdClass(EmployeeID.class)
   public class EmployeeDetail {

   @MapsId("groupId")
   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "GROUP_ID", insertable=false , updatable=false)
   private EmployeeGroup employeeGroup;

   @Id
   @Nonnull
   @Column(name = "EMPLOYEE_ID")
   private Long employeeId;
```

Comment: MapsId I already tried and similar exception I received while trying a fix for this issue. Like grouId cannot be null.

Comment: ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - NULL not allowed for column "GROUP_ID"; SQL statement:
insert into EMPLOYEE_DEPARTMENT (GROUP_ID, DEPARTMENT_ID, HEADER_ENG, HEADER_GE, DEP_NAME, DEP_ADDRESS) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) [23502-197]
16:22:17.396 [https-jsse-nio-auto-1-exec-6] ERROR o.h.i.ExceptionMapperStandardImpl - HHH000346: Error during managed flush [org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement]
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is

Comment: but you add a group to the employee? You cannot save an employee that has no group assigend

Comment: yes because if you see EmployeeId class it has both groupId and departmentId, so if we do not add group to the employee then it will fail during build saying no groupId defined in EmployeeDetail class. I agree with your point without a group employee details wont be saved. But this is not working for me with the mapping you suggested. Or I dont know if I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Entity
   @Table(name="EMPLOYEE_DEPARTMENT")
   public class EmployeeDepartment {

   @Column(name = "DEPARTMENT_ID")
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = 
      "departmentid-gen")
   @Id
   @NotNull
   @SequenceGenerator(name = "departmentid-gen", sequenceName = 
     "DEAPARTMENT_ID_GENERATOR" )
   private  Long departmentId;

   @OneToOne(mappedBy = "employeeGroup")
      private EmployeeGroup employeeGroup;
      }
  @Column(name="GROUP_ID") 
  private EmployeeGroup group;




   @Entity
   @Table(name="EMPLOYEE_GROUP")
   public class EmployeeGroup {

   @Column(name = "GROUP_ID")
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = 
      "groupid-gen")
   @Id
   @NotNull
   @SequenceGenerator(name = "groupid-gen", sequenceName = 
     "GROUIP_ID_GENERATOR" )
   private  Long groupId;

   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "employeeDetail")
      private List<EmployeeDetail> employeeDetails;

  @OneToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "DEPARTMENT_ID", insertable=false , 
        updatable=false)
      private EmployeeDepartment employeeDepatment;
      }



@Entity
   @Table(name = "EMPLOYEE_DETAIL")
   @IdClass(EmployeeID.class)
   public class EmployeeDetail {

  @Id
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "GROUP_ID", insertable=false , updatable=false)
  private EmployeeGroup employeeGroup;

  @Id
  @Nonnull
  @Column(name = "EMPLOYEE_ID")
    private Long employeeId;
```

You also need to change the EmployeeId accordingly:

```
public class EmployeeId{

private EmployeeGroup employeeGroup;

private Long employeeId;

public EmployeeId(final EmployeeGroup employeeGroup, final Long employeeId) {
    this.employeeGroup= employeeGroup;
    this.employeeId = employeeId;
}
```

However I haven't use composite keys this way before. If it doesn't work, then change EmployeeId to an embeddedId:

```
@Embeddable
public class EmployeeId implements Serializable{

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
private EmployeeGroup employeeGroup;

@Nonnull
@Column(name = "EMPLOYEE_ID")
private Long employeeId;

public EmployeeId(final EmployeeGroup employeeGroup, final Long employeeId) {
    this.employeeGroup= employeeGroup;
    this.employeeId = employeeId;
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "EMPLOYEE_DETAIL")
public class EmployeeDetail {

  @EmbeddedId
  private EmployeeId id;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "GROUP_ID", insertable=false , updatable=false)
  private EmployeeGroup employeeGroup;

}
```

If it still doesn't work, then please attach the code snippet where you create the entities.